# How to set multiple boolean mutators

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 and I have a model with a lot of boolean attributes.

For each of them I'm setting a setter like this

```
public function setIsRemoteAttribute($value){
    $this->attributes['isRemote'] = !!$value;
}
```

and a getter like this

```
public function getIsRemoteAttribute($value){
    return !! $this->attributes['isRemote'];
}
```

Is there any way to abstract that out so I'm not individually setting 12+ mutators?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can override `setAttribute` method like:

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value){
    if(in_array($key, 'abstract_keys')){
        $this->attributes[$key] = !!$value;
    }
    else{
        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Same would go for `getAttribute`.

Comment: Struggling to get this working. Would I need to add the attributes to my `$appends` array?

Comment: You can add them wherever you want them to be stored. For example in some private property like ```private booleans = ['property', 'property2'];``` etc. Then instead of ```abstract_keys``` you use ```$this->booleans``` and that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have L5 installation but I'm pretty sure this will apply to L4.2 as well.

If you look in the code for Eloquent's Model class you will find the following method:

```
/**
* Set a given attribute on the model.
*
* @param  string  $key
* @param  mixed   $value
* @return void
*/
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    // First we will check for the presence of a mutator for the set operation
    // which simply lets the developers tweak the attribute as it is set on
    // the model, such as "json_encoding" an listing of data for storage.
    if ($this->hasSetMutator($key))
    {
        $method = 'set'.studly_case($key).'Attribute';

        return $this->{$method}($value);
    }

    // If an attribute is listed as a "date", we'll convert it from a DateTime
    // instance into a form proper for storage on the database tables using
    // the connection grammar's date format. We will auto set the values.
    elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) && $value)
    {
        $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
    }

    if ($this->isJsonCastable($key))
    {
        $value = json_encode($value);
    }

    $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
}
```

You could potentially, override this function in your own model:

- Store a list of attributes that should get the boolean mutator
- Check if `$key` is within this list of elements
- If it is - do something
- If it's not, default to the parent implementation (This method)

Example:

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if (in_array($key, $this->booleans))
    {
        // Do your stuff here - make sure to return it
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}
```

You can do the same thing for the `getAttribute` method.

With this approach, all you need to do is add the names of the attributes to the list of booleans for them to work.

```
protected $booleans = array('attr1', 'attr2');
```